# Why does my MacOS app disappear on the dock when run/build on Xcode?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Ever since I updated my Xcode to 14.0, when I run my MacOS app it shows up on the dock for a second and then disappears. The App is still running however if I click away it stays hidden. I never had this problem in Xcode 13.

Replicating this bug:

1. Run App on Xcode
2. App shows up on Dock and bounces
3. App disappears on Dock
4. App is still running
5. Clicking out of App causes the app to disappear
6. Pressing F3 to find the app in the background, if I click it, the app vanishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. When I created another target, it was the same name as the MacOS file except a capitalized letter on it. Seems that it confused git and overwritten the MacOS file

Comment: I have the same issue. what do you mean by "same name as the MacOS file"? what file?

Answer (score 0):

Startup or boot your Mac in the safe mode!

Here is the link to follow:

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mh21245/mac